# Nodal analysis for resistive circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, ltspice, spice, nodal-analysis

Given the following circuit:

[image]

I know that `I1 = I2 + I3`, but what would be the relationship between I2,I3,I4, and I5?

I would assume if there are 5 unknowns, we'd need to have five equations to solve for this, so something like:

```
# voltage
I1*100 + I2*200 + I4*500 = 5 # top
I1*100 + I3*300 + I5*400 = 5 # bottom
I2*200 + I4*500 - I5*400 - I3*300 = 0 # I2->I4->I5->I3 loop

# current
I1 = I2 + I3
I2 + I3 = I4 + I5
```

But then, if I plug these equations in, it doesn't seem like it's enough to solve for all the currents. Am I missing any equations in the above to solve for I1-I5?

By the way, I tried plugging in what I got into an equations solver, and got the following error:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([
    # current
    [1,-1,-1,0,0], # i1 = i2+i3
    [0,1,1,-1,-1], # i2+i3 = i4+i5

    # voltage
    [100,200,0,500,0],
    [100,0,300,0,400],
    [0,200,-300,500,-400],
])
B = np.array([0,0,5,5,0])
A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A)
i1,i2,i3,i4,i5=np.matmul(A_inv,B)
> ERROR: numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Which equation(s) does it seem like I'm missing or getting incorrect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3KiiE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Most people would just tell you to combine parallel resistors, leaving a simple series of three remaining resistors to work through. But let's not do that. You asked about nodal.

Nodal (KCL) would have the following:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_X}{R_1}+\frac{V_X}{R_2}+\frac{V_X}{R_3}&=\frac{V_\text{CC}}{R_1}+\frac{V_Y}{R_2}+\frac{V_Y}{R_3}\\\\
\frac{V_Y}{R_2}+\frac{V_Y}{R_3}+\frac{V_Y}{R_4}+\frac{V_Y}{R_5}&=\frac{V_X}{R_2}+\frac{V_X}{R_3}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_4}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_5}
\end{align*}$$

I've placed out-flowing currents on the left and in-flowing currents on the right, above. That's two equations and two unknowns.

Using sympy:

```
var('vx vy vcc r1 r2 r3 r4 r5')
(vx, vy, vcc, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5)
eq1=Eq(vx/r1+vx/r2+vx/r3,vcc/r1+vy/r2+vy/r3)
eq2=Eq(vy/r2+vy/r3+vy/r4+vy/r5,vx/r2+vx/r3+0/r4+0/r5)
ans=solve([eq1,eq2],[vx,vy])
for item in ans:item,ans[item].subs({r1:100,r2:200,r3:300,r4:400,r5:500,vcc:5})
(vy, 500/199)
(vx, 770/199)
for item in ans:item,ans[item].subs({r1:100,r2:200,r3:300,r4:400,r5:500,vcc:5}).n()
(vy, 2.51256281407035)
(vx, 3.86934673366834)
```

You can work out the currents from these voltages.

---

If you want to use KVL then:

$$\begin{align*}
V_\text{CC}-I_{R_1}\cdot R_1 - I_{R_2}\cdot R_2-I_{R_5}\cdot R_5 &= 0\:\text{V}\\\\
V_\text{CC}-I_{R_1}\cdot R_1 - I_{R_3}\cdot R_3-I_{R_4}\cdot R_4 &= 0\:\text{V}\\\\
V_\text{CC}-I_{R_1}\cdot R_1 - I_{R_3}\cdot R_3-I_{R_5}\cdot R_5 &= 0\:\text{V}\\\\
I_{R_1}&=I_{R_2}+I_{R_3}\\\\
I_{R_1}&=I_{R_4}+I_{R_5}
\end{align*}$$

That's five equations and five unknowns.

Using sympy:

```
var('ir1 ir2 ir3 ir4 ir5')
(ir1, ir2, ir3, ir4, ir5)
eq3=Eq(vcc-ir1*r1-ir2*r2-ir5*r5,0)
eq4=Eq(vcc-ir1*r1-ir3*r3-ir4*r4,0)
eq5=Eq(vcc-ir1*r1-ir3*r3-ir5*r5,0)
eq6=Eq(ir1,ir2+ir3)
eq7=Eq(ir1,ir4+ir5)
ans0=solve([eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7],[ir1,ir2,ir3,ir4,ir5])
for item in ans0:item,ans0[item].subs({r1:100,r2:200,r3:300,r4:400,r5:500,vcc:5})
(ir2, 27/3980)
(ir4, 5/796)
(ir1, 9/796)
(ir3, 9/1990)
(ir5, 1/199)
for item in ans0:item,ans0[item].subs({r1:100,r2:200,r3:300,r4:400,r5:500,vcc:5}).n()
(ir2, 0.00678391959798995)
(ir4, 0.00628140703517588)
(ir1, 0.0113065326633166)
(ir3, 0.00452261306532663)
(ir5, 0.00502512562814070)
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I got it working! Here's an example: https://imgur.com/a/qus4GRq. I was having a lot of trouble using the `numpy` linear algebra solver, so I moved over to using `sympy`, which I had never heard of before until you mentioned it -- thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @David542 That's kind of a waste. You have the same current along an *edge* into a resistor as along an *edge* away from that same resistor. I'm sure someone a long time ago duplicated your approach. But it's been discarded and no one remembers it anymore. Nodes in a circuit are the wires. Not the parts. I know it feels better to you right now to make the parts a node, because you can have many or a few edges to handle the number of pins a device has. But this isn't how it's done. And it's actually WRONG for many reasons.

Comment: @David542 Is there a reason why you are trying to re-invent a "graph theoretic" approach to schematics?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Yes the resistor (or any component) can be thought of as being on the incoming edge, with a small wire (or whatever) on the outgoing edge. I'm really just doing this to help myself understand how to write the equations, actually, and so far it's helped me quite a bit in doing so.

Comment: @David542 You may be able to communicate with yourself with your system. I'm not going to tell you that you cannot make it work. I've seen crazier ideas that produce the right answers. But very smart people a long, long time ago have developed very much better approaches which have stood the test of time and require very few assumptions. You should learn KCL and KVL and just stick with that.

Comment: yes, of course. It's been fun though to learn it, and without trying to do it I don't think I would've gotten as deep into figuring out the components and how to solve them (for example, with sympy) without it.

Comment: @David542 Are you familiar with the matrix notation used for graph connections? If you are a programmer, you should become familiar with that notation. If you ask a separate question, I can provide some software examples along with the associated data structures used. Or else you can just read about one method here: [Wikipedia on the adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). The idea already can provide either one-direction or bi-directional connections and can be expanded from there, too.

Comment: A bit: I'm using an adjacency list for the graph structure. Let me look at the adjacency matrix and see how similar it is and all. Graph stuff is pretty neat though, I've enjoyed learning up about that.

Comment: @David542 Also, I just located [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/53745212.pdf) that may be of interest. There are much, much older papers that cover similar stuff but in much, much greater depth. But I thought you might be interested in something simple and easy to get through. (See some of the references listed at the bottom of that paper, for example.) Please note that this paper places the devices along the graph as ***edges*** and not as ***nodes***. It also uses some "tricks" of a sort that allows for separating a node into several nodes.

Comment: thank you, I will take a look!

Comment: @David542 I applaud the fact that you use your own imagination. And sometimes, it's better to do that *before* you read what others have written because it keeps their ideas from blocking your own. But you should proceed only so far along that line before then developing a comprehensive view of the work of others. I don't know when the best time for learning from others is. Sometimes, right away. Sometimes, only after pursuing your own thoughts for a few years. But at some point, you need to do that and find out what others think and understand it in order to weight your own insights.

Comment: @David542 In my teens (about 17) I had read Einstein's own writing on developing his special theory of relativity. It starts with but two separate equations: \$x=c\,t\$ and \$x^{'}=c\,t^{'}\$. It only requires simple algebra from there and I was able to follow it at 17 with ease.

Comment: @David542  But I asked myself, what do those two equations signify about reality? After spending months on it, I realized it expresses two completely isolated coordinate systems with only one shared reality between them, \$c\$. An insight suddenly arrived: that fermions exist in isolated universes of their own -- totally alone -- no dimensions at all. And that bosons (which carry both distance and time as \$c\$ has those dimensions) *connect* these isolated fermions. Out of these connections, a space-time reality emerges.

Comment: @David542 But the remaining question in my mind was, "Do all the fermions connect in some way to all others through bosonic entanglements? Or do only some of them?" I realized I didn't know, for sure. The big bang might say "yes" but I know that entanglements are lost through dissipation and other ones emerge. So I then realized that there must be slightly different sub-realities within our universe. It is only in the last year or so that physical experiments are now showing that the reality in Lab 1 is incompatible with the reality in Lab 2!

Comment: @David542 So use your imagination! But... temper it, too.

Comment: thank you very much for the encouragement and kind words :)

Comment: I think I've gotten something a bit more representative of how a circuit would work. It seems to be an improvement, and from here I'll start using something that's already been built to further my electronics education :)
https://imgur.com/a/TJ9DZP5

Comment: @David542 Okay. That's both easier and harder to read than before. So you have resistors as both edges and nodes, now?

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I think it's a limitation in how I'm modeling the components. For example, here's comparing the resistor component in EveryCircuit to my (python) graph. Both would have the main 'component' in the middle (the jagged line for the resistor, but I can only model it will a colored ball) and two leads on either side. Here's an example: https://imgur.com/a/LoZgace. Does that make sense?

Comment: all right, here's my final attempt: https://imgur.com/a/HFWlIBC. I think beyond this it gets more into geometry and the shape of the graph and look of the components (i.e., a resistor symbol, a battery symbol, etc.) than in the connections themselves. Thanks again for all your help on this.

Comment: @David542 That's looking better, I think.

Answer (score 2):

When performing nodal analysis you want to solve for the node voltages, not the branch currents. After you know the node voltages you can use Ohm's Law to calculate the branch current in each resistor.

I'll redraw your circuit as shown in Figure 1. Note that there are two nodes whose voltages are unknown: \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$. Therefore, you'll need to derive two equations to solve for these two unknown voltages. Use Kirchhoff's Current Law to derive these two equations—i.e., the sum of the currents at each node is zero.

[image: schematic_figure_1]

*Figure 1.*

Recall from Ohm's Law that

$$
I_R = \frac{V_R}{R}
$$

Use Kirchhoff's Current Law and nodal analysis to derive an equation at node \$V_A\$:

$$
\frac{V_A-V_B}{R2} + \frac{V_A-V_B}{R3} + \frac{V_A-0}{R4} + \frac{V_A-0}{R5}=0
$$

Use Kirchhoff's Current Law and nodal analysis to derive an equation at node \$V_B\$:

$$
\frac{V_B-5}{R1} + \frac{V_B-V_A}{R2} + \frac{V_B-V_A}{R3} = 0
$$

*(NB: Pay close attention to how I defined the voltages across the resistors in each equation. When performing nodal analysis at node \$V_A\$ I always subtract the neighboring node voltage from \$V_A\$.  Likewise, when performing nodal analysis at \$V_B\$ I always subtract the neighboring node voltage from \$V_B\$. The advantage of this method is that you do not need to know in advance the actual direction of current flow in each resistor.)*

Now use whatever method you like to solve for \$V_A\$ and \$V_B\$. Once you know those two node voltages you can use Ohm's Law to solve for the current in each resistor.

**HINT**

This analysis can be simplified if you realize that resistors R2 and R3 are connected in parallel and therefore they can be replaced by a single resistor Rx whose value is the parallel combination of R2 and R3.  Likewise, resistors R4 and R5 are connected in parallel and they can be replaced by a single resistor Ry whose value is the parallel combination of R4 and R5.  Your two equations are now

$$
\frac{V_A-V_B}{Rx} + \frac{V_A-0}{Ry} = 0 \\
\frac{V_B-5}{R1} + \frac{V_B-V_A}{Rx} = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

The vertical wire between the left ends of 400Ohm and 500Ohm resistors binds currents: I2+I3 = I4+I5.

BTW starting by combining parallel resistors to one and then resistors in series to one would be the usual calculation method for practical electricians. With it you would get I1 as the first result.

**ADD due the edits in the question:** Your problem is not too few equations, its too many equations. Your equations are no more independent, they present same facts several times and thus the equation group is linearly dependent which is told in words "singular matrix".

If you want to keep this complexity right, write for ex.

5=100 * I1 + 200 * I2 + 500 * I4

I1 = I2 + I3

200 * I2 = 300 * I3

500 * I4 = 400 * I5

I2 + I3 = I4 + I5

Comment: thanks, it seems that I'm missing some equations other than the i2+i3=i4+i5 equivalence. I know this isn't a practical approach, but do you have any idea which equations I might be missing to tie things together? I've updated my question above.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the feedback. What would be the correct equations then (I would assume I would need 5 for a system of equations with 5(?) unknowns).

Comment: thank you, those equations worked (when put into a linear equation solver).